# Data corrupted when passed from one Ruby method to another?

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec

I'm trying to pass several parameters of class `Integer` to one of two methods—the pick is determined by the final parameter passed to the initial method.

The problem is described in full [here](https://github.com/JoshCheek/ruby-kickstart/blob/master/session3/challenge/14_var_args_and_hash.rb), but in short, my methods should correctly count the no. of chains of 2+ identical digits when multiple digits are passed in with a final param of 
`:problem => :count_clumps`.

i.e. `problem_14(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, :problem => :count_clumps)` should return `2`, as it contains 2 chains of 2+ identical digits.

I'm failing an rspec test for the following:
`problem_14(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, :problem => :count_clumps)`
My methods should return `2`, but they return `0`.

I think the problem is with whatever `problem_14` is passing to `count_clumps`. `count_clumps` passes rspec tests when tested directly, but returns the wrong result when invoked via `problem_14`.

```
def problem_14(*parameters)
  if parameters[-1].is_a?(Hash)
    parameters.pop[:problem] == :same_ends ? same_ends(parameters) : count_clumps(parameters)
  else
    count_clumps(parameters)
  end
end

def same_ends(n, *array)
  return true if n == 0
  array[0..n-1] == array[-n..-1]
end

def count_clumps(*array)
  count = 0
  clump = false
  array.each_index do |x|
    if array[x] == array[x+1]
      clump = true
    else
      count += 1 if clump
      clump = false
    end
  end
  return count
end
```

I'd appreciate any pointers on where I'm going wrong with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby, the splat (*) operator takes all parameters and turns them into an array. So when you do this:

```
def problem_14(*parameters)
```

You're taking a list of params and putting them into the array called `parameters`. Then when you call `count_clumps(parameters)` you're passing in an array, but since your `count_clumps` method also expects a list of parameters which gets turned into an array:

```
def count_clumps(*array)
```

What you end up with is a double array, like this:

```
[[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]]
```

The fix is actually pretty simple. When you have an array, you can use splat (*) to turn it back into a parameter list. Just do this:

```
parameters.pop[:problem] == :same_ends ? same_ends(*parameters) : count_clumps(*parameters)
```

Comment: Technically when calling a method it's a splat, but when declaring it that's a *var-args* declaration, a form of splat but with the opposite effect: It makes things into an array instead of converting from array to args. Your explanation is pretty close, but it's sort of two sides of the same coin here.

Comment: @tadman i haden't heard of *var-args* declaration before. after looking into it more, i realized that "splat" is just a slang term for the symbol itself `*` sort of like how `#` is crunch, `!` is bang and `/` is whack. thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple problem's with this. First the array needs to be flattened and your not  comparing the value with the next index instead your comparing value to value + 1.

```
def count_clumps(*array)
  count = 0
  clump = false
  array = array.flatten
  array.each_with_index do |x, a|
    if x == array[a+1]
      clump = true
    else
      count += 1 if clump
      clump = false
    end
  end
  return count
end

puts problem_14(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, :problem => :count_clumps)
 => 2 
puts problem_14(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, problem: :count_clumps)
 => 2 
puts problem_14(1, 1, 1, 1, problem: :count_clumps)
 => 1
```